# How to connect different deep learning architectures?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Based on 5 features extracted from a sample of binary files, the idea is to combine different deep learning models each of them processing one feature sample.

Or simply is there a way to connect a CNN and a RNN, in a way that the output of the CNN would be the input of the RNN ?

Any help or reference would be appreciated

Comment: Does this help you out? https://wiki.tum.de/display/lfdv/Recurrent+Neural+Networks+-+Combination+of+RNN+and+CNN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Keras [Functional API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional) can be used to combine different Deeplearing models.

It is much more flexible than the Keras Sequential API, in that it can support multiple input, output pipelines.

You can implement non-linear topology with the Functional API.

For example:

[image: A multi-input model]